# lua cmd can not recognize in macos though i installed

Tags: bash, lua

I install lua success in my mac, but i got "-bash: lua: command not found" message when i run lua cmd, but i run /usr/loca/bin/lua success, i confirm the path that lua installed is included in PATH. I record some information as follow:
lxr:bin wang$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
lxr:bin wang$ echo $PATH
.;/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:JAVA_HOME/bin
lxr:bin wang$ lua
-bash: lua: command not found
lxr:bin wang$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
lxr:bin wang$ ls -l
total 872
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      80 11 23 00:40 VBoxAutostart
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      82 11 23 00:40 VBoxBalloonCtrl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      80 11 23 00:40 VBoxBugReport
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      77 11 23 00:40 VBoxDTrace
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      79 11 23 00:40 VBoxHeadless
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      77 11 23 00:40 VBoxManage
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      79 11 23 00:40 VBoxVRDP
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      77 11 23 00:40 VirtualBox
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      14  3 28  2016 git -> ../git/bin/git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      37  3 28  2016 git-credential-osxkeychain -> ../git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      24  3 28  2016 git-cvsserver -> ../git/bin/git-cvsserver
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      20  3 28  2016 git-shell -> ../git/bin/git-shell
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      26  3 28  2016 git-upload-pack -> ../git/bin/git-upload-pack
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      15  3 28  2016 gitk -> ../git/bin/gitk
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  221128 12  1 15:53 lua
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  150520 12  1 15:53 luac
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2670 11 28  2014 pstorm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1394  3  8  2017 ssh-copy-id
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      75 11 23 00:40 vbox-img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      77 11 23 00:40 vboxwebsrv
lxr:bin wang$ ./lua
Lua 5.3.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> 
lxr:bin wang$

Comment: BTW, I suggest you install Lua 5.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two characters in $PATH should probably be `.:`, not `.;`.